# filter_var boolean returning false

Tags: php, boolean, filter-var

This is weird

```
var_dump(filter_var(true, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
var_dump(filter_var(false, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));

bool(true)
bool(false)
```

What an I missing here? Surely they should both be true? If not how can I validate a false boolean?

Edit: To clarify.
I need to validate a false boolean. To ensure it's not a string, int, float or anything else.
e.g.

```
$var = false; //true
$var = true; //true
$var = 'foo'; //false
$var = 1; //false
```

Perhaps I asked my question incorrectly or I've evolved it too much ad I should ask another question.

Solution I went for was:

```
$result = filter_var($bool, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) && ($bool===true||$bool===false);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The [manual](http://php.net/manual/filter.filters.validate.php) says `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` "_Returns TRUE for "1", "true", "on" and "yes". Returns FALSE otherwise._"

Comment: My question is: how can I validate a false boolean?

Comment: Set `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE`? And when in doubt, you can go back to strict comparisons (`return $x === true || $x === false`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual:-

> If FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE is set, FALSE is returned only for "0", "false", "off", "no", and "", and NULL is returned for all non-boolean values.

Set this and if `null` is returned, you don't have a bool (or boolish) value.

For example:-

```
var_dump(filter_var(true, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE));
var_dump(filter_var(false, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE));
var_dump(filter_var(2, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE));
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/BA4an)

However, it may be that [`is_bool()`](http://php.net/is_bool) is more appropriate here.

Comment: NULL is returned on a false boolean too. So how can I validate a variable is a false boolean?

Comment: No, null is returned only for a non boolean(ish) value if you set FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE. eg 1 would return null, but 0 would return false.

Comment: Brilliant! That's what I expected the output of FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN to be.